# How to scan both qr-code and barcode with the same app?

Tags: swift, barcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have a ticket with both a printed QR-code and a barcode. But I am stuck with parsing/scanning both codes. If I put the following the app only scans the QR-code

```
metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
// I can't use them both I need to skip AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode to scan barcode
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
```

and to scan the barcode I need to delet AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
```

I like to be able to scan both, QR-code and barcode?
And i am not sure if the other types are necessary

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of simultaneous detections is 4, this number is only for 2 dimensional barcodes. 1 dimensional barcode recognition is limited to 1 detection. See this reference for more info:

[Apple: Technical Note TN2325](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2325/_index.html)

So, this rules out the simultaneous detection of 2D and 1D barcodes.